# How to parameterize ODBC;DSN and excel sheet path in Excel running as SQL - (From Other Sources -> From Microsoft Query)

Tags: excel, vba

I am working on "From Other Sources - > From Microsoft Query" and below is the code which i am comparing between sheet1 and sheet2. It is not working as expected and getting error message "Not a valid path" at the last line.

Could you please help me on this?

```
Sub filter()
Dim filename As String
Dim defaultdirpath As String
Dim src As Workbook

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
filename = Application.GetOpenFilename
defaultdirpath = Left(filename, InStrRev(filename, "\") - 1)
Set src = Workbooks.Open(filename, True, True)



    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
    With ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:=Array(Array( _
        "ODBC;DSN=Excel Files;DBQ=defaultdirpath;    DefaultDir=filename;DriverId=1046;MaxBufferSize=2048" _
        ), Array(";PageTimeout=5;")), Destination:=Range("$A$1")).QueryTable
        .CommandText = Array( _
        "SELECT `Sheet1$`.column1, `Sheet1$`.column2, `Sheet1$`.column3, `Sheet1$`.test, `Sheet2$`.column1, `Sheet2$`.column2, `Sheet2$`.column3, `Sheet2$`.test" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "FROM `filename`.`" _
        , _
        "Sheet1$` `Sheet1$`, `filename`.`Sheet2$` `Sheet2$`" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "WHERE `Sheet1$`.column1 = `Sheet2$`.column1" _
        )
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .BackgroundQuery = True
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .PreserveColumnInfo = True
        .ListObject.DisplayName = "Table_Query_from_Excel_Files"
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: If your path has spaces in it, you may need to wrap it in double quotes.  Use debug and show us what your path name looks like.

Comment: I think path is passing correctly, but the macro code itself has some issue is what I am guessing.